# Javascript, Jquery Open new tab from users input by adding that input to a custom url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying get this open a new tab when the user clicks "click"

I have a custom URL and when the user inputs a value it adds that value to the end of the custom url that i define in the script.

Current Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#click').click(function() {
        var url = "CustomURL";
    url += $('#q').val();
    window.location = url;
});
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="q" target="newwindow" />
<input type="button" id="click" value="click"  />
```

I'm trying get it to open a new Window when the user clicks 'click'.

Thanks in advanced.

This is my first post so excuse the lack of structure, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    <script type = "text/javascript" > $(function () {
    $('#click').click(function () {
        var url = "CustomerUrl";
        url += $('#q').val();
        var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
        win.focus();
    });
```

Comment: Rep 6, Soon as i get 15 (If i do, i'll +1 it) Put it on my Important Reminders!

Comment: @LeonardSmith you can accept it as answer, if youre happy with it.

Comment: @Craicerjack How do you do that? *Sorry first time as a user. ***DONE***